# "RuntimeError: working outside of application context" for config module

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a config.py module that I call from my main file, it has a variety of app.configs for jinja2filters and some other plugins I'm using:

excerpt of config.py:

```
from flask import current_app as app  
#imports go here

def function1:
    print("hello")

app.config['PROPERTY_1'] = 'configgoeshere'

#jinja2 functions and configs would go here like
app.jinja_env.filters['datetime'] = datetimeformat
```

calling from index.py:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, jsonify, request, json, request, redirect, url_for, Response, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = False

app.config.from_object('config') #config file

############################################################################################################################
# MAIN ROUTES
############################################################################################################################
# The route for the homepage
@app.route('/')
def index():
```

returns the error:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

**Update**
I'm trying to pass the application context along now, here is index.py:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, jsonify, request, json, request, redirect, url_for, Response, send_from_directory
import time, datetime, os, urllib, urllib2, urlparse, requests, json, string
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError, urlparse

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = False

app.config.from_object('config')


############################################################################################################################
# MAIN ROUTES
############################################################################################################################
# The route for the homepage
@app.route('/')
def index():
```

Here's the updated excerpt config.py:

```
from index import app
#imports go here

def function1:
    print("hello")

app.config['PROPERTY_1'] = 'configgoeshere'

#jinja2 functions and configs would go here like
app.jinja_env.filters['datetime'] = datetimeformat
```

The error returned is:

```
$ python index.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "index.py", line 8, in <module>
    app.config.from_object('config')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\config.py", line 162, in from_object
    obj = import_string(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\utils.py", line 418, in import_string
    __import__(import_name)
  File "C:\Users\****\Desktop\*****\config.py", line 1, in <module>
    from index import app
  File "C:\Users\***\Desktop\*****\index.py", line 17, in <module>
    @app.route('/')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 343, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 302, in _get_current_object
    return self.__local()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\globals.py", line 34, in _find_app
    raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

Note - there is no code on line 162 inside of config.py like the error suggests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out Flask's explanation of [Application Contexts](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/appcontext/#creating-an-application-context).

In your `config.py` file, the `from flask import current_app as app` makes it so that the call to `app.config['PROPERTY_1'] = 'configgoeshere'` actually tries to set the config on `current_app`, though there's no application context by default until a request comes in (hence the error). Since that call is not within a function, it is executed immediately before anything else (like a request) can happen.

I would suggest doing the config on the `app` instance in index instead of on `current_app`.

Comment: I really would like to keep it in a separate file because it adds too many lines to my main file.  Is there a way I can "pass" on the application context from index onto the config file?  I've looked into solutions like __ init __.py or blueprint for flask, but they seem like overkill

Comment: In `config.py`, you could import `app` from `index` instead of `current_app` and set the config there.

Comment: I have added `app.config.from_object('config')` to index.py and `from index import app` to config.py but am still getting the error message `RuntimeError: working outside of application context` ... any ideas?

Comment: Did you remove the `from flask import current_app as app`? I ran the code with no problems, unless there's code you aren't showing. Would suggest updating the question or asking another, since comments section doesn't appear to be the best place for this.

Comment: Four years late, but this is happening to me to. It seems to simple, but I just get the same error over and over. What was the answer @24x7?

Comment: @AllenGingrich I've added a new post below of the outline of the code I ended up using.  Hopefully it can be of use to you too.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using exactly what karin described.

index.py

```py
from __future__ import print_function # For printing output to CMD
import sys

from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, jsonify, request, json, request, redirect, url_for, Response, send_from_directory
import os, urllib, urllib2, urlparse, requests, json, string
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError, urlparse

app = Flask(__name__)

from config import * 
// ... rest of code for main file (like routes and stuff) below
```

config.py

```py
from flask import Flask, current_app

app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    // code goes here ...
    // in this case, I'm configuring various services like API's and jinja2
```